# OpenGL blurry in WinForms (but not in WPF)

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms, opengl

I'm researching an issue that a Windows Forms application using an OpenGL surface draws a blurry plot whereas a WPF application using **the same** WinForms OpenGL surface (embedded via XAML `WindowsFormsHost`) is sharp.

#### Screenshots

WPF application:

[image: OpenGL plot in a WPF application]

Windows Forms application:

[image: OpenGL plot in a Windows Forms application]

#### Details

Both applications use `OpenTK.GLControl` to draw the plot.
OpenTK version: 1.1.1173.43181 (newer versions are not compatible with legacy code).

The WPF application hosts the control in a `WindowsFormsHost`, so the underlying code basis is the same. I've researched any settings that may be different between the applications in regards of the OpenGL plot but couldn't identify anything that influences the graphic quality or anti-aliasing settings.

Mind you, all form data (ie. textual content, other controls) of the WinForm application is sharp.

Other users report the same problem (to rule out hardware misconfiguration).

Is there anything I may be overlooking or is this blurriness an expected behavior of OpenGL in WinForms applications?

#### Update

I followed the instructions of the article [High DPI support in Windows Forms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/high-dpi-support-in-windows-forms) but the blurriness of the plot is still the same.

Comment: A random guess: maybe this has something to do with the DPI-awareness?

Comment: The PC has set scaling to 100% and the application does **not** call ``SetProcessDPIAware()`` at startup. I also tried to set different AutoScaleModes but the blurriness of the plot is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to get rid of the blurriness was to remove the plot control and add it to the form again.

Comment: But of course this answer does not address the root cause. What was different between before and after?